# Why are $E_{d(d)}$ representations labelled by integers?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, supergravity

Reducing 11d supergravity on a torus $T^d$ or, equivalently, IIB supergravity on $T^{d-1}$, one gets an exceptional $E_{d(d)}$ hidden symmetry, which is, in particular, the *non-compact* split real form of the exceptional groups $E_d$. However, when one does exceptional field theory, one often labels the irreps with integers (see e.g. [this review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.08312.pdf)). My understanding is that non-compact groups have at least one continuous parameter labeling the irreps (e.g., mass for Poincare irreps or scaling dimension for conformal irreps), so why don't we have that here?

Comment: Are you perhaps comparing apples with oranges here? The *finite-dimensional* representations of the Poincaré group are also just labeled by two half-integers $(s_1,s_2)$, e.g. $(1/2,1/2)$ for vectors and no continuous parameter, it's the unitary infinite-dimensional representations that are labeled by continuous mass (and spin). Are you looking at finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional representations of $E_{d(d)}$ here?